# Dynamic change of items title in Action Bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

What I am trying to do is: change the title of an item in Action Bar from `onClick` method.
Code of `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);    
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

My `option_menu.xml` of menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/state"
      android:title="@string/title_not_connected"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

The title should change from `onClick` method in class below:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class ReceiveSectionFragment extends Fragment {
        public NotificationCenter mNotificationCenter;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receive, container, false);
            mNotificationCenter = new NotificationCenter();
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_server_start)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    MenuItem item = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.state);
                    item.setTitle(TAG);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to find this item in menu by Id but I am getting this error: `The method findItem(int) is undefined for the type R.menu`. I am using fragments and `ReceiveSectionFragment` uses `R.layout.receive` layout.

How can I deal with this problem? Possibly, I am doing it all wrong by using wrong methods.

**I am not using ActionBar Sherlock.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `InvalidateOptionsMenu` when you want to make changes to the ActionBar menu.

You then override `onCreateOptionsMenu` to rebuild your menu with your changes in place. You cannot edit a menu outside of the methods provided for building menus.

Every time you call `InvalidateOptionsMenu` your menu will be rebuilt by the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method so you need to make all of your changes there.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

This is true whether you are using ActionBarSherlock or not.

e.g:

Set a variable to hold the title

```
String MyMenuTitle = "Default Menu";
```

Your OnClick

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    MyMenuTitle = "My New Menu Title";
}
```

Your Menu Building Code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu); 

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.state);
    item.setTitle(MyMenuTitle);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: I added `invalidateOptionsMenu ()` but I can not still build my project due to: `The method findItem(int) is undefined for the type R.menu`

Comment: Then you are calling it in the wrong place. You do not have access to the menu from your OnClick handler.You have to call findItem in OnCreateOptionsMenu. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Yes but what I really what to achieve is to setup various titles of this specific `Item` based on which button was clicked so it does not help. Even if I use `invalidateOptionsMenu ()` I will be constantly  setting the title as `"New Title"`...

Comment: This is the only way to do it. If you want to change a menu, you have to call invalidateoptionsmenu, let onCreateOptionsMenu rebuild your menu. You have to include the code to rebuild your menu in the new state there by using conditional statements.

Comment: "New Title" was an EXAMPLE. You should use the variable or value that you actually need. e.g In your OnClick set String MyMenuTitle = "My New Menu Title" the use that in the menu building process. Please read my full answer again. You have not understood it. I did not explain how to use variables as that is basic and I assumed you knew that. I have updated the answer again with a step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the following lines in the fragment in which you want to hide the menu.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    MenuItem item = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.your_action);
    item.setVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this without InvalidateOptionsMenu..

first declare the MenuItem as static before the onCreate Method..

```
  static MenuItem item;
```

Then initialize handler in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    item = menu.findItem(R.id.state);

    return true;
}
```

Finally use setTitle whenever you want to change your title...

```
 item.setTitle("your title");
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

**Its Working**

**static MenuItem item;  // Define Global Variable**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.minu_filter, menu);
        menu.findItem(action_enter_manually).setVisible(true);
        // allocation id 
        item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_enter_manually);
    }
```

**call Where**
  item.setTitle("your title");